# Support for MSP430x5xx processors on MSP430-gcc

Tags: msp, msp430

How would I add support for a new MSP430 processor type on MSP430-gcc? E.g. msp430x5xx series.

I understand I must produce the relevant *.h/.o* files but how do I generate/integrate those in msp430-gcc ?

Comment: Have you checked the newest GCC (gcc4) version to make sure it isn't done already? Have you mentioned your intentions on any (gcc) relevant forum?

Answer (score 2):

http://travisgoodspeed.blogspot.com/2008/09/retargetting-mspgcc-linker.html

Answer (score 0):

I think they are now supported, as of the latest mspgcc release, dubbed temporarily  "uniarch"

Here are some instructions on how to install it on ubuntu

https://github.com/sergiocampama/Launchpad/blob/master/README.md